# Conv json obj w/ varying keys & key:value pairs to python list for specific keys:values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, key

I have received a json file from an api and want to convert it from to a `dictionary` to a `list` in python. I already have it loaded as a python dictionary, so I'm really just looking to iterate over it and convert from a dictionary to a list. However, the dictionary has nested lists and not every object within the json file's many objects is always structured the same (i.e. the api will not always return the same json object for every event). I want to convert the dictionary to 3 separate lists, each list for a specific key:value pair I am parsing for.

I've tried using `KeyError` in a try/except statement to account for cases where there is no value but haven't had much luck. Also tried importing defaultdict from collections to no success as well. I gather I should be able to make the rests of my lists once I get some help with this first one. Hopefully I didn't overcomplicate the question

```
data = load_json()# function responsible for loading the json from a stored file
new_list = []

for some_key1 in data
    if new_list['some_key1'] > 0:
        try:
            new_list.append(['some_key1'], some_key1)
        except:
            new_list.get(['some_key1'], '0')

for x in range(len(new_list)):
    print(new_list[x])
```

I am looking to make one list for storing each object's (i.e. each python 'breaking' dictionary) key:value pair where `some_key1` exists (i.e. this means in this case I will have a list for `aDifferentCherry` and `yetAnotherDifferentCherry`.

Comment: [{'breaking': 'aCherry'},
 {'value_x': {'N/A': 'N/A',
    'country': 'blah',
    'domains': '1',
    'name_servers': ['some.name.server_a',
        'some.other.name.server_b'],
    'some_key1': ,
    'some_key2': 3},
 'something1': somethingelse1},

Comment: {'breaking': 'aDifferentCherry'},
 {'value_x': {'N/A': 'N/A',
    'country': 'blahblah',
    'domains': '2',
    'name_servers': ['some.name.server_c',
        'some.other.name.server_d',
        'some.name.server_j',
        'some.name.server_k'],
    'some_key1': 5},
 'something1': somethingelse2},

Comment: {'breaking': 'anotherDifferentCherry'},
 {'value_x': {'N/A': 'N/A',
    'country': 'blahblahblah',
    'domains': '3',
    'name_servers': ['some.name.server_e',
        'some.other.name.server_f']},
    'some_key1': ,
 'something1': somethingelse3},

Comment: {'breaking': 'yetAnotherDifferentCherry'},
 {'value_x': {'N/A': 'N/A',
    'country': 'blahblahblahblah',
    'domains': '4',
    'name_servers': ['some.name.server_g',
        'some.other.name.server_h',
        'some.other_i],
    'some_key1': 3,
    'some_key2': 9,
    'some_key3': 10},
 'something1': somethingelse3},
]

Comment: ***NOTE:*** Above are desperate attempts to give an example of the json contents, seeing now that it is a list with nested dictionaries and lists

Comment: ***NOTE***: I am getting a "KeyError: 'some_key1'" traceback error using the code at the moment